# LARAVEL 5.2 - How to access login page as default page

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I just need to know how i can set the login page as default page of my site.

```
Route::get('/', function () {
     return view('welcome');
});
```

I need something like this:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('auth.login');
});
```

It's possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, just put this route before all other routes and this will work.

If you're using standard Laravel 5.2 auth system, you can create this route and use it before all other routes:

```
Route::get('/', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
```

Comment: did not work: 

2/2
ErrorException in 8e374217110bc1783be61c9cba0b71cbff61e31c.php line 13:
Undefined variable: errors (View: C:\wamp64\www\Mobi-Delivery-System\resources\views\auth\login.blade.php)

Comment: Well, you should make your original login system work perfectly. If it works and you still get the message, wrap your `$error` messages displaying with `@if (isset($error)) .... @endif` clause.

Comment: Thanks man for help me.

I make like this and work:

<code>
 Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    //
    Route::get('/', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
});
<code>

Comment: yes, this works. But after login, if you try to access site base URL like www.example.com, its causes a redirection loop. How to solve that?